# string variable in for loop iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below program, As we know String is immutable in python, if we reassign the values to the string in python new variable is created (reference).

```
S = "Nagu"
print (id (S))

S = "Santh"
print (id (S))
```

output :

```
43578232
43578288
```

In the below program traversal of the list names being done,

```
names = ["nagu","santh"]

for name in names:
    name = "K." + name
    print("{0} : {1}".format(id(name),name))
```

output:

```
43579688 : K.nagu
43579688 : K.santh
```

the name variable in the for loop gets different value from the list without changing the id how it is possible?

Comment: what's the problem? I don't see it. Please provide your desire solution

Comment: @Gahan, the problem is "the `name` variable in the for loop gets different value from the list *without changing the id*" and how it is possble?

Comment: honestly I don't see why it should provide you the same id, think of lists in other languages  you "allocate" a node for the first string, and you allocate a node for the second string, no reason to have the same id whatsoever

Comment: because it is iterating, let's say if your for loop ends after count of 100 you will get only 100th value as a result for the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = ["nagu","santh"]

for name in names:
    print("before assignment -- {0} : {1}".format(id(name),name)) # you will get different ids before assignment
    name = "K." + name # you are now assigning value to variable name for temporary which has lifespan of a single loop
    print("{0} : {1}".format(id(name),name))
```

Result:

```
before assignment -- 2856389816760 : nagu
2856391256640 : K.nagu
before assignment -- 2856391254624 : santh
2856391256640 : K.santh
```

In a normal flow, when you reassign a value, its id still exists.
But in a 'for' loop, when you iterate over list items, the previous reference to id is freed when the loop completes one cycle (at the beginning of the next cycle, the memory will be freed.)

Comment: Thanks Gahan for answer